# Disabling link of post or post types wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to disable access on links of a post or post type?
Say I have a post type called soldiers, then I will input solider's names and information on each post.
I made a loop to show all soldiers on a table for comparison and filtering instead letting them see each one on a single page.
If I make the posts private, the url will be inaccessible, but the posts on loop have private on its name, and taxonomies and other complicated loops blocks them.

I am looking to disable access to urls of the solider post type or even each post.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a copy of the template file that post uses, rename that to `single-soldiers.php` or `archive-soldiers.php` (depending which file is used originally) and edit that file to *not*  contain the permalink which is wrapped around the header or/and the thumbnail.

For example, in a typical theme, that part could look like this:

```
  the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
```

Now just remove the opening and closing `<a>` tag, like this:

```
the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title">', '</h2>' );
```

The result looks the same, except that there is no link on the title.

Another example: In theme 2017 the code for the linked thumbnail looks like this:

```
<div class="post-thumbnail">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' ); ?>
  </a>
</div>
```

Again, remove the `<a>` tag around the thumbnail to avoid the link:

```
<div class="post-thumbnail">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' ); ?>
</div>
```